# Centering Axes using tight_layout()

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

All,

I'm trying to export figures in (roughly) a particular size so I can include them in high-res in my LaTeX document. When I draw the figure, the ylabel is cutoff (I assume because my figure is small, 2.7in wide). When I call tight_layout(), I get the labels fine, but now the axes are no longer center in the saved image. I need the axes centered above the caption, so I want the axes centered on the image.

I tried adding a second axis to the right side, but I couldn't figure out how to make the labels and ticks invisible for that axis.

Here is without tight_layout()

[image: default]

Here is with tight_layout()

[image: tight_layout()]

Any idea how I can get the best of both worlds (everything visible, with the axes centered)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and it seems there is no elegent way after I  googled it. I ended up with the `fig.subplots_adjust`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([10,20,30])

plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('silver')
fig.set_size_inches(w=3.5, h =3)
# %%
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.85, bottom=0.15, top=0.9)
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

But this will produce additional padding around the axes and tedious parameter-tuning...

[image]

while `fig.tight_layout()` produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to test it on the code. But try playing with `axes.set_position()` as shown here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-axes-axes-set_position-in-python/amp/